# Where to find the question I asked on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

Where is my first question?  I would like to accept an answer and vote.  I am an old Linux programmer and I cannot find my question so I can vote/accept.

Comment: It's in your profile. Click your name, up in the menu, and you will find it. At the bottom left are a bunch of sites where you have accounts. Go to the correct one, if you happen to view your profile on another site.

Comment: [Here's the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513929/oracledatasource-connection-is-null-after-using-it-4-times). I got this exactly how @J.Steen described: through your Stack Overflow profile, under the questions section.

Comment: And as you need 15 reputation (for example: 3 upvotes on a question) to upvote, hopefully some people will follow the link that @thegrinner posted... ;-)

Comment: There's a chance your first question got deleted so try going to the Questions tab in your profile and in the bottom you will see "deleted recent questions" link. Click it and hopefully you'll find your question, though you won't be able to vote or accept anything there.

Answer (score 5):

It's in your profile. Click your name, up in the menu, and you will find it. At the bottom left are a bunch of sites where you have accounts. Go to the correct one, if you happen to view your profile on another site.

<sub>[copied from comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190139/where-to-find-the-question-i-asked-on-stack-overflow#comment588692_190139)</sub>

Comment: Thanks. I habitually fire off comments on meta, since it's the helping (in these particular one-off cases) that matters. =)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find the list of your questions, visit your Stack Overflow profile (you can do that be clicking your nickname on the top of the site) : https://stackoverflow.com/users/2558387/sylvia-graham